# Loading SQLite table in R with RSQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite, r-dbi

I had this function I used to load a SQLite table

```
sqLiteConnect <- function(database, table) {
  library(DBI)
  library(RSQLite)
  con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = database)
  query <- dbSendQuery(con, paste("SELECT * FROM ", table, ";", sep="")) 
  result <- fetch(query, n = -1, encoding="utf-8")
  dbClearResult(query)
  dbDisconnect(con)
  return(result)
}
```

But now it seams it generates an error

```
album <- sqLiteConnect("~/Downloads/ChinookDatabase1.3_Sqlite/Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite","Album")

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"character"’
Called from: stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
    sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
```

(I downloaded the db from [here](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/55169#DownloadId=167067))

Is it a bug or a problem with my function?

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0 igraph_0.7.1  RSQLite_1.0.0 DBI_0.3.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.2       gtable_0.1.2    
 [5] MASS_7.3-35      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10    
 [9] Rcpp_0.11.3      reshape2_1.4     scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2   
[13] tools_3.1.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [github](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/issues/57)

```
library(DBI)
dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ...)
```