# Importing a SSN object into R and getting "unable to find an inherited method"

Tags: r, r-dbi, rsqlite

Similar to: [Loading SQLite table in R with RSQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824540/loading-sqlite-table-in-r-with-rsqlite)

Receiving an error when I try to import a statistical stream network object. Has anyone worked with the SSN Cran R package and seen this error?

[SSN: An R Package for Spatial Statistical Modeling
on Stream Networks](https://www.fs.usda.gov/rm/boise/AWAE/projects/SSN_STARS/downloads/SSN/SSNvignette2014.pdf)

```
install.packages("SSN")
install.packages("RSQLite")
install.packages("DBI")
#for stream network analysis
library("SSN")
library("RSQLite")
library("DBI")
dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())
    ssnME <- importSSN("/Volumes/CGA 2015 Conference/NHDplus_LSNetwork/lsn_ME.ssn")


>dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())
    <SQLiteConnection>
 
>ssnME <- importSSN("/Volumes/CGA 2015 Conference/NHDplus_LSNetwork/lsn_ME.ssn")
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbDisconnect’
> for signature ‘"function"’

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix to my question was using one line of code and changing the directory from an external hard-drive to a desktop folder:

```
dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())
```

and the folder of my SSN object was moved to my desktop.

Issue has been fixed.